# Finding an inverse of a polynomial modulo some other polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

1) $x^3-3x-1$ is irreducible by the rational root test.

2) $L=\Bbb Q[x]/\langle x^3-3x-1\rangle$ is therefore a field.

3) $f(x) = x^4+2x^3+3\in L$. $f(x)\cong 3x^2+7x+5 + \langle x^3-3x-1\rangle$

4) I want to find $\frac{1}{x^4+2x^3+3} +\langle x^3-3x-1\rangle$

I am allowed to immediately substitute $x^4+2x^3+3$ for $3x^2+7x+5$ and then find $h(x)$ such that $(3x^2+7x+5)(h(x))=1$ Which would be $$(3x^2+7x+5)(h(x))=1 + \langle x^3-3x-1\rangle$$
I guess, not sure how to get that to work. Thanks

Comment: There may be shortcuts, but the Euclidean Algorithm is always available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Use the euclidian algorithm on $f(x) := 3x^2 + 7x + 5$ and $g(x) := x^3 - 3x - 1$ to find polynomials $a, b \in \mathbf Q[x]$ such that 
$$ a(x) \cdot (3x^2 + 7x + 5) + b(x) \cdot (x^3 - 3x - 1) = \gcd(f,g) = 1 $$
In $L$ you have then 
$$ (a + \left<g\right>)\cdot (f + \left<g\right>) = 1 + \left<g\right>$$

Comment: Hmm I am bad at using the Euclidean algorithm it seems or maybe it truly is a super slow process by hand?

I have $x^3 - 3x - 1 = (\frac x3 - \frac79)(3x^2+7x+5)+(\frac{7x}{9} + \frac{26}{9})$ for the first step

Answer (score 0):

Here’s another method, probably no less work than using Euclidean Algorithm:

Write your unknown reciprocal as $ax^2+bx+c$, multiply this by your $3x^2+7x+5$ to get $3ax^4+(7a+3b)x^3+(5a+7b+3c)x^2+(5b+7c)x+5c$, if I have been less than my usual careless self. Then divide by $x^3-3x-1$ to get a remainder of $(14a+7b+3c)x^2+(4a+14b+7c)x+(7a+3b+5c)$, again modulo my own carelessness. Then set the three parenthesized quantities to $0$, $0$, and $1$ respectively, to get three linear equations in the three variables. It would seem that the determinant of your matrix is $111$, not exactly a pretty little number, but it all ought to work out.